# Errors referencing custom view in View Controller

Tags: iphone, ios

I've assigned a custom view class for a View Controller in Interface Builder. The referencing outlet in the View Controller for the "view" is a valid "CustomView", and the view object in Interface Builder has been assigned a custom class of "CustomView". However, when I try to reference specific properties of "CustomView" in my View Controller, through its "view" property, I get errors. I think its because it still believes its a UIView class, and not my "CustomView" class.

Is there a way to update the View Controller's class definition of its "view"?

Answer (score 1):

If you're sure you have a CustomView object linked to 'view' use a cast to give the compiler a hint, like:

```
[(CustomView *)view doSomething];
```

or

```
((CustomView *)view).stringProperty = @"Hello";
```

If you want it to be safe, check that `view` really is a member of the CustomView class before making the call.

Comment: Thanks Phillip. I was able to use casting to access properties of the CustomView class. I guess I was looking for a way to get around having to do that.

Comment: The only other thing I've seen is creating your own CustomView property, linking it in IB, and using it instead of 'view'.  It adds a bit of overhead with extra setting and releasing but not too bad if you like the non-cast coding.